# Connect to mysql on Amazon EC2 from a remote server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to connect to db on EC2 from my local machine, I am not able to do and have tried everything- 
I am using this command to connect to EC2:

```
mysql -uUSERNAME -hEC2_IP -pPASSWORD
```

This error is generated

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (110)

I have modified my.cnf with

```
skip networking
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Still not able to connect to the database

Comment: can you SSH onto the EC2 instance? If so then what happens when you try to connect to the mysql database locally i.e. from the same EC2 instance on which the database is installed?

Comment: You can take reference from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56251251/4701635)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There could be one of the following reasons:

1. You need make an entry in the Amazon Security Group to allow remote
   access from your machine to Amazon EC2 instance. :- I believe this
   is done by you as from your question it seems like you already made
   an entry with 0.0.0.0, which allows everybody to access the machine.
2. MySQL not allowing user to connect from remote machine:- By
   default MySql creates root user id with admin access. But root
   id's access is limited to localhost only. This means that root user
   id with correct password will not work if you try to access MySql
   from a remote machine. To solve this problem, you need to
   allow either the root user or some other DB user to access MySQL from remote
   machine. I would not recommend allowing root user id accessing DB
   from remote machine. You can use wildcard character % to specify any remote machine.
3. Check if machine's local firewall is not enabled. And if its enabled
   then make sure that port 3306 is open.

Please go through following link: [How Do I Enable Remote Access To MySQL Database Server?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: and make sure you are adding rules to the group associated with your instance. I wasted good couple hours because of that.

Comment: when you install mysql server on windows server, it will ask you for grant access right for port 3306, but this is not enough, it will ask for private and domain network, if you access from public network, you need to add public access to port 3306. This is why I can't access to mysql just now.

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql) article helped me.

Answer (score 92):

as mentioned in the responses above, it could be related to AWS security groups, and other things. but if you created a user and gave it remote access '%' and still getting this error, check your mysql config file, on debian, you can find it here: /etc/mysql/my.cnf and find the line:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

and change it to:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

and restart mysql.

on debian/ubuntu:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: removing/commenting out bind-address= was the solution for me

Comment: this was the solution for me too.  after checking and confirming every other possible setting imaginable i finally ended up on this answer. thanks!

Comment: This is the actual solution. It should have been accepted as Answer

Comment: Yes this the correct answer when working with EC2 / /MySql db. I seem to visit this page about every 6 months. Thanks!

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, this bind-address is located in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf.

Answer (score 70):

### ***Update:*** Feb 2017

> Here are the **COMPLETE STEPS** for remote access of MySQL (deployed
>   on Amazon EC2):-

### 1. Add MySQL to inbound rules.

Go to security group of your ec2 instance -> edit inbound rules -> add new rule -> choose `MySQL/Aurora` and source to `Anywhere`.

### 2. Add bind-address = 0.0.0.0 to my.cnf

In instance console:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

this will open vi editor.
in my.cnf file, after `[mysqld]` add new line and write this:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Save file by entering `:wq`(enter)

now restart MySQL:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

### 3. Create a remote user and grant privileges.

login to MySQL:

`mysql -u root -p mysql` (enter password after this)

Now write following commands:

```
CREATE USER 'jerry'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'jerrypassword';

CREATE USER 'jerry'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'jerrypassword';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to jerry@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'jerrypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to jerry@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'jerrypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

EXIT;
```

After this, MySQL dB can be remotely accessed by entering public dns/ip of your instance as MySQL Host Address, username as jerry and password as jerrypassword. (Port is set to default at 3306)

Comment: Hi Jerry,
I followed everything step by step as you suggested.But still not able to access remote database on AWS EC2 instance.I have posted my issue on this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112414/not-able-to-connect-mysql-database-from-remote-server-on-amozon-ec2-server

Comment: did you execute all scrips from step 3? I noticed you didn't mention all scripts in that question

Comment: after creating the user.. try mysql -u yournewuser -p mysql from same server..  are you able to login?

Comment: Yes, I have executed all the queries you suggested.And I am able to login with newly created user on localhost.But can't access remotely.

Comment: Editing the file /etc/my.cnf does nothing here. I had to edit
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf (ubuntu 16.04 -> sudo apt install mysql-server).

Comment: The hell my.cnf is empty

Comment: Hi Jerry, I followed your steps carefully in vain. I got (Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out)  any suggestion?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 AWS, I found my.cnf at /opt/lampp/etc# vi my.cnf

Comment: I had to combine this with Bob Diego's answer below (to replace step 2) for this to work.

Comment: This is THE answer.

Comment: You don't need the IDENTIFIED BY clause in the GRANT command

Comment: On Ubuntu 20 using old 5.6 MySQL installation, got to config file using: sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Answer (score 32):

It could be that you have not configured the [Amazon Security Group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) assigned to your EC2 Instance to accept incoming requests on port 3306 (default port for MySQL).

If this is the case then you can easily open up the port for the security group in a few button clicks:

1) Log into you AWS Console and go to 'EC2'

2) On the left hand menu under 'Network & Security' go to 'Security Groups'

3) Check the Security Group in question

4) Click on 'Inbound tab'

5) Choose 'MYSQL' from drop down list and click 'Add Rule'

Might not be the reason but worth a go...

Comment: So others don't think this won't affect them, having the default "All traffic, All, All, sg-...." did not allow it, possibly because to the source value. But an additional row "MYSQL,TCP,3306,0.0.0.0/0" worked

Comment: I already do that for PostgreSQL port 5432 please specify the terminal command for remote database connection..

Answer (score 23):

A helpful step in tracking down this problem is to identify which bind-address MySQL is actually set to.  You can do this with netstat:

```
netstat -nat |grep :3306
```

This helped me zero in on my problem, because there are multiple mysql config files, and I had edited the wrong one.  Netstat showed mysql was still using the wrong config:

```
ubuntu@myhost:~$  netstat -nat |grep :3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

So I grepped the config directories for any other files which might be overriding my setting and found:

```
ubuntu@myhost:~$  sudo grep -R bind /etc/mysql
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:bind-address         = 127.0.0.1
/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf:bind-address = 0.0.0.0
/etc/mysql/my.cnf:bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

D'oh!  This showed me the setting I had adjusted was the wrong config file, so I edited the RIGHT file this time, confirmed it with netstat, and was in business.

Comment: This is exactly the solution. The main issue is locating the right my.cnf file which in this case is searched in sudo grep -R bind /etc/mysql

Comment: This was a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

For some configurations of ubuntu, the bind-address needs be changed in this file:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Comment: This suggestion helped me

Answer (score 5):

Though this question seems to be answered, another common issue that you can get is the DB user has been mis-configured.  This is a mysql administration and permissions issue:

1. EC2_DB launched with IP `10.55.142.100`
2. EC2_web launched with IP `10.55.142.144`
3. EC2_DB and EC2_WEBare in the same security group with access across your DB port (3306)
4. EC2_DB has a mysql DB that can be reached locally by the DB root user (`'root'@'localhost'`)
5. EC2_DB mysql DB has a remote user `'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'`
6. A bash call to mysql from EC2_WEB fails: `mysql -umy_user -p -h ip-10-55-142-100.ec2.internal` as does host references to the explicit IP, public DNS, etc.

---

Step 6 fails because the mysql DB has the wrong user permisions.  It needs this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my_user'@'ip-10-55-142-144.ec2.internal' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'password'
```

I would like to think that `%` would work for any remote server, but I did not find this to be the case.

Please let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Change `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0
```

Create user with '%' `host` and restart:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Works for me! :)

Answer (score 4):

Update on new MySQL 5.7 on AWS EC2

The my.cnf file in /etc/mysql will only be having

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

**DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE....MYSQL WILL BLOCK THE CHANGE**

Instead, just go to
`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/`

There, you should find a file named `mysqld.cnf`

Here, you will find

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Change it to

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0 <OR> <Your IP>
```

THAT'S IT!!!. SAVE THE FILE AND RESTART MYSQL.

**DO NOT DO ANY OTHER CHANGES LIKE 'SKIP-NETWORKING'. THIS SHOULD WORK**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I followed for remote connection with MySQL installed on Ec2:

1. Edit the following line in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

   ```
   bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

   to

   bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
   ```
2. Create New user to remotely connect to mysql from any machine. Mention the machine ip instead of ‘%’ if you only wanted to remotely acces mysql from specific IP.

> ```
> CREATE USER 'master'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'write-password-here';
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.* TO 'master'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
> ```

3. In the inbound rules of the security group of your Ec2 instance add a row having values MYSQL/Aurora, TCP, 3306 and source=0.0.0.0/0

Finally connect with MySQL from the remote machine by

```
mysql -u master -h write-server-ip -p
```

Answer (score 2):

Log into AWS Management Console. Navigate to RDS then select the db instance and go to "security Groups". Adding CIDR/IP under the security group  fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but...

I'm experiencing this issue and I've established that my problem is in fact not the EC2 instance. It seems like it might be a bug in the MySQL client driver software. I haven't done thorough research yet but I went as far as to install MySQL Workbench on the EC2 instance and IT also is erratic - it intermittently fails to connect (error is "connection cancelled"). [This link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64003) suggests a possible bug lower down the stack, not EC2.

Of course, I have not done exhaustive research and my post might actually be off the mark, but worth noting and/or exploring anyway, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this is three steps:

1. Within MySQL my.ini/ my.cnf file change the bind-address to accept connection from all hosts (0.0.0.0).
2. Within aws console - ec2 - specific security group open your mysql port (default is 3306) to accept connections from all hosts (0.0.0.0).
3. Within windows firewall add the mysql port (default is 3306) to exceptions.

And this will start accepting remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

- START MYSQL using admin user

  - mysql -u admin-user -p (ENTER PASSWORD ON PROMPT)
- Create a new user:

  - CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; (% -> anyhost)
- Grant Privileges:

  - GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE ON db_name.* TO 'newuser'@'%';
  - FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

If you are running EC2 instance don't forget to add the inbound rules in security group with MYSQL/Aurura.

If these steps didn't work check /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and edit the 
bind_address param as

> bind_address=0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

For AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.x and 20.x

1. Head over to the EC2 console.
2. Then to Security Groups.
3. The Security Group that is associated to your instance
4. Edit Inbound Rules
5. Add New Rule. Select MySQL/Aurora then select Source to anywhere.
6. Finally Follow this tutorial from digital ocean on how to setup a remote database connection that is optimised.

Tutorial link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-remote-database-to-optimize-site-performance-with-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the previous answers (and answers to similar questions) without success, so here is what finally worked for me. The key step was to explicitly grant privileges on the mysql server to a local user (for the server), but with my local IP appended to it (`myuser@*.*.*.*`). The complete step by step solution is as follows:

1. Comment out the `bind_address` line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` at the server (i.e. the EC2 Instance). I suppose
   `bind_address=0.0.0.0` would also work, but it's not needed as
   others have mentioned.
2. Add a rule (as others have mentioned too) for MYSQL to the EC2 instance's security group with port 3306 and either `My IP` or `Anywhere` as Source. Both work fine after following all the steps.
3. Create a new user `myuser` with limited privileges to one particular
   database `mydb` (basically following the instructions in this [Amazon tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html)):

   ```
   $EC2prompt> mysql -u root -p
   [...omitted output...]
   mysql>  CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_strong_password';
   mysql>  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mydb'.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';`
   ```
4. Here's the key step, without which my local address was refused when attempting a remote connection      `(ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '*.*.*.23' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server)`:

   ```
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mydb'.* TO 'myuser'@'*.*.*.23';
   mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
   ```

   (replace `'*.*.*.23'` by your local IP address)
5. For good measure, I exited mysql to the shell and restarted the msyql server:

   `$EC2prompt> sudo service mysql restart`
6. After these steps, I was able to happily connect from my computer with:

   `$localprompt> mysql -h myinstancename.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u myuser -p`

   (replace `myinstancename.amazonaws.com` by the public address of your EC2 instance)

Answer (score 0):

While creating the user like 'myuser'@'localhost', the user gets limited to be connected only from localhost. Create a user only for remote access and use your remote client IP address from where you will be connecting to the MySQL server. If you can bear the risk of allowing connections from all remote hosts (usually when using dynamic IP address), you can use 'myuser'@'%'. I did this, and also removed bind_address from /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf (Ubuntu) and now it connects flawlessly.

```
mysql> select host,user from mysql.user;
+-----------+-----------+
| host      | user      |
+-----------+-----------+
| %         | myuser    |
| localhost | mysql.sys |
| localhost | root      |
+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default ip of Mysql in instance EC2 
Ubuntu is `127.0.0.1` if you want to change it is just to follow the answers that have already been given here.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was experiencing was that my database network settings allowed *outbound* traffic to the web – but *inbound* only from select IP addresses.

I added an *inbound rule* to allow traffic from my ec2's private IP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Hack

1. Our EC2 MYSQL server will be hosted at `remotehost:3306` using

`port forwarding` we can forward this remote port to our `localhost:3307` and

the use MYSQL workbench to connect to `localhost:3307'

2. Make sure to edit inbound rules of your ec2 instance to allow traffic on

port 3306

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself unable to connect to port 3306, it could be blocked by your ISP, local firewall, router, modem, or other network configurations.

**Verifying the Issue**

To diagnose this, try connecting to an external MySQL server, like db4free.net:

```
telnet db4free.net 3306
```

If you're unable to establish a connection, it's likely that the issue resides on your side.

**A Potential Solution: Setting Up a Tunnel**

Should you face this issue, one workaround is to create a tunnel using a different port. While there are various methods to achieve this, here's how I did it on a Linux server using Nginx:

First, ensure the ngx_stream_module.so is installed. Then, add the following to nginx.conf:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen [Your_Chosen_Port]; # Example: 50000
        proxy_pass [Your_RDS_Endpoint_or_MySQL_Server]:3306;
    }
}
```

Using this approach, you can bypass the blockage on port 3306 and connect through another port of your choosing. Also, confirm that the new port you've chosen is configured to allow incoming connections in your Security Group settings.

**Important:** Whenever you open a new port, ensure that it's properly secured to prevent unauthorized access.