# Remote access to MySQL on Amazon EC2 Windows instance

Tags: mysql, windows, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I found some solutions for Linux [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766014/connect-to-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-from-a-remote-server).

But didn't find any solution for Windows. I don't have my.cnf on Windows. I only have my.ini. there is no bind-address in it.

I have already added an inbound rule for MySQL.

Could anybody give me some advice? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would check:

1. Verify that the MySQL service is up and running by remote desktop'ing to the instance and trying to connect to it on the instance.
2. If that checks out, try modifying or disabling Windows Firewall to ensure that outside machines can connect on the relevant port. Depending on the Windows version, there might be several places that you need to fiddle with this (i.e. both Windows Firewall and Windows Firewall with advanced security).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Asp.Net Application with Entity Framework, you will need to install the MySQL connector on the EC2 instance (I would suggest running `iisreset` to make sure the dll's are loaded).