# Can not remote access to MySQL on Amazon

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Before I try to remote access to MySQL, something have been done:

1: Login Using SSH

2: Edit the my.cnf file, add the following line: bind-address=SERVER-IP, comment skip-networking, then restart the mysql server

3: Grant access to remote user:
   mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
   mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO username@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

4: Logout SSH

The system is SUSE Linux, the current status of firewall is disabled and the status of port SERVER-IP:3306 is listen

Then I try to access to MySQL: $ mysql -u username –h SERVER-IP –p

Error occur: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '*.*.*.*' (60)

Any idea? Thanks for helping

Comment: The only thing noticed is after you granted permission on the account, did you run this command **flush privileges;**

Comment: Yes, I run this command flush privileges

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to mysql on Amazon EC2 from a remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766014/connect-to-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-from-a-remote-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have disabled the firewall, but I'm not sure if you mean the system firewall or the Amazon security group port blocking.

You probably have to set the Security Group in the Amazon EC2 security groups pane. You can do this by going to the Security Groups and add the mysql ports to your active security group on inbound tcp.

Comment: I check the status of firewall by yast firewall: it says Firewall is not running

Comment: @user2986212 Yes but you don't have Amazon's security groups disabled. The machine's firewall may well be fine but Amazon's routers will block anything not whitelisted in the security groups.