# connect phpMyAdmin to MySQL server on EC2

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, pem

I am new to this, any help is appreciated.

I am running phpMyAdmin on my local ubuntu machine. I want to access my mysql database on my Amazon-EC2 instance which is running ubuntu as well. Is there anyway to do this?

To connect to EC2 using ssh I am using a pem keyfile. How should I configure phpMyAdmin to use this file for login?

Comment: you can have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766014/connect-to-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-from-a-remote-server

Comment: thanks, I was wondering if there is an easy way to connect to the general ubuntu@EC2_IP user (on an Ubuntu EC2 instance). My  Do I need to have a user account with SUPER privilege in mysql?   (ps I have modified the security group on EC2 to accept connections to mysql)

Comment: you can use restful api