# Connecting MySQLWorkbench to Amazon Web Services EC2 Instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have no idea how to connect mySQL to amazon EC2 Instance. Here is the screenshot of mySQL workbench: [mySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlXAl.png). I try to change the HostName to the Public IP being provided by the instance, however when i press test connection, it keep promoting this error: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUhgV.png). So what should i do as of now? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

> Since I cannot put a comment, pardon me for putting this to the
>   Answers Section

Error 10060 is a generic error that means your client cannot reach the server.

- Try pinging your server IP, if it responds, it is online.
- Are you sure that the port that EC2 uses is also 3306? Configure your EC2 Instance to allow remote connections. Check the EC2 Security features, something might be blocking you.
- AFAIK, the root user is only limited to localhost. So it won't work if you use it remotely. Create a new user with the privileges that you only need, then use the '%' wildcard which means any host.

And finally, you may want to try this: [Step by Step instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9767032/6294600)

Answer (score 1):

In your EC2 instance you will have a Security Group Column. 
Click on that will open the security group page  
In the bottom of the page you have a tab called **Inbound**  
Click **Edit** and then **Add Rule** to allow port 3306. 
In source select **anywhere** option.