# Not able to connect MySQL database from remote server on Amazon EC2 server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

1. I am using MySql Version 5.7.17 with centos-7 on AWS EC2 Instance(**Server1**)
2. I have added entry "bind-address=0.0.0.0" in "/etc/my.cnf"
3. Added inbound rule in security group for port 3306 with 0.0.0.0/0
4. Added new user and assigned all privileges with following queries
5. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO bob@'%' identified by 'password';
6. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
7. Another EC2 instance(**Server2**) is on same VPC.

Still,I am not able to connect MySQL database from remote server(**Server2**) to server(**Server1**).

Comment: what's the error you getting?

Comment: also, try with root user in server B

Comment: Already tried with all the users.And error is "Permission denied"

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when trying to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote db connection is working now.

I run following command on remote server(**Server2**)

**setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1**