# Laravel: Call 1 ec2 instance from ec2 instance in .env file

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instance; my 1st EC2 instance is for my projects; my 2nd EC2 instance for the database

Is it possible to call the other EC2 in my .env file coming from my 1st EC2 instance?

Comment: You might want to look for this: [Connect to mysql on Amazon EC2 from a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766014/connect-to-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-from-a-remote-server)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the IP address of the second EC2 instance in the first instance. You can find the IP address in the AWS console or by running a command such as **ifconfig** or **ipconfig**.

Add in .env file.

```html
DB_HOST=10.0.0.2 # IP address of your second EC2 instance
DB_PORT=3306     # port number of your database
DB_USER=database_username # your database username
DB_PASS=database_password # your database password
```

Let me know if this working or not.

Comment: is it the ipv4 address?

Comment: When I changed the DB_HOST=<public ip address>, it gives me an error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. "

Comment: Yes. it was Ipv4 address.

Comment: It gives me an error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. "

Comment: It might be possible to change the  security group settings or DNS lookup issues.